# Use XSP4 in MonoDevelop

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, .net-4.0, mono, monodevelop, xsp

I´m currently trying to get a MVC 2 (.NET 4.0) application running on Mono, but I´ve got some problems with the XSP server.

Everything is fine, when I press the "Run" button in MonoDevelop. My application starts using the correct version of ASP.NET:
**Mono Runtime Version: 2.8 (tarball Tue Oct 5 14:16:19 MDT 2010); ASP.NET Version: 4.0.30319.1**

When I try to debug my application, MonoDevelop always uses the wrong ASP.NET version:
**Mono Runtime Version: 2.8 (tarball Tue Oct 5 14:16:19 MDT 2010); ASP.NET Version: 2.0.50727.1433**

Does anyone know how I can change this?

Regards,
Philip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>The current trunk does not use xsp4 during debugging.</strike>

I pushed my branch to http://github.com/silk/monodevelop/tree/xsp4 with that small change.

Master branch of monodevelop now supports xsp4 for debugging both on Linux and Windows.

Comment: Looks correct, could you send a pull request? Btw, ideally it should also handle xsp4 for the Windows/.NET case, and report an error in the case of an unrecognized version.